# Spring REST - At least one RequestParameter mandatory

Tags: spring, rest

I have a method with below `RequestMappings`:

```
@RequestParam(value = "someValue1", required = false) final String someValue1
@RequestParam(value = "someValue2", required = false) final String someValue2
```

Both the parameters are marked as optional. And currently I check which attribute is provided and based on that some action is taken. Is it possible to enforce at least one of the two parameters should always be present in the request?

PS: I am not looking at creating two different end points.

Comment: I don't think that there are interdependent checks for the params. But why not validate them in your method?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing. But was looking around in case there is a more elegant way of doing that.

Comment: I assume that a solution for such a requirement would make the annotation  lose its elegancy ;-) Nevertheless an absolutely valid question.

Comment: I was looking for the same concept, I think the best is to validate all params in the method, with a negative response in case no params are sent.

Answer (score 0):

Just send the request parameter as a String map and mark that as mandatory attribute.

```
        public @ResponseBody String your_method(
   @RequestParam(value = "parameterMap", 
    required = true) Map<String,String> params){

                //String someValue1 = params.get("someValue1");
                // String someValue2 = params.get("someValue2");
            }
```

Here you have to pass either or both of the parameters.

Comment: This is incorrect. You can still pass a Map with no values in it.

Comment: So, in theory, this should work: `@RequestParam(required = true) @NotNull @Size(max = 1) Map<SearchParamEnum, String> params` where `SearchParamEnum` is the list of param names accepted.

Comment: @VijayKalidindi will me request query params need to change in any way to have this work? I don't want to still be able to give my params in the request as simple query params.

Comment: Also @VijayKalidindi what would the enum SearchParamEnum look like.